# How can I auto-restart a ruby script on windows?

Tags: ruby

I need to restart a script when it fails. My script fails because of a Ruby runetime bug which is another issue...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might be cleaner ways of doing it, but it seems the obvious way is to have a separate process running that monitors the first one. If it is not running, restart it.

You can [enumerate processes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684865.aspx) and get information about the [command line and other details](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684298.aspx) in order to know which script is being run.

Comment: Follow up, is this much easier on linux?

Comment: It is probably about the same amount of work.  I don't have the information on how to do it in Linux at my fingertips.

Comment: @Zombies:  I just had a moment to refresh my memory on the Linux side of it.  I *think* the standard way is to enumerate the "files" in /proc.  You can use `opendir` to enumerate those and retrieve details.